# Data warehousing: how does denormalized data facilitate business intelligence applications?

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence, data-analysis

I understand that most queries used in data analysis are read only and are looking at historical data so it is much faster when data in the database is de-normalized. But I also understand that there is got to be more to it. Can anyone please elaborate?

Comment: Another reason in it simplifies the data model. You don't have to go joining all kinds of tables to get to the attribute you need. If it's about a customer, it's in the customer dimension end of story. It's not necessarily faster, it's just waaaay simpler for BI tools to use a star schema (i.e. where dimensions contain all the info and you don't have to join all kinds of tables)

Comment: Look into "The Data Warehouse Toolkit" by Ralph Kimball, it goes into great depth in explaining why denormalized data is more suitable for BI. F

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other resource I can look through without having to purchase and read an entire book